# How to show data from a csv file on web page in tabular form

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql, file-io

I am working on a system where i need to select millionsof records from mysql and there is no key is defined on that table as there is mass inserting and updating work simultaneously .

So I use this command  to a genrate csv file from selected data and its working for me in great way  .

```
SELECT *
INTO OUTFILE 'E:\\31october\\SP\\Export\\xyz.csv'
FIELDS
  TERMINATED BY ','
  OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  ESCAPED BY '\\'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM tblspmaster;
```

but my problem is i also have to update the selected records and needs to show those records on `aspx` page . if i run select its just running and running .

So I have two questions

1. How can I update another fields in that table using `INTO OUTFILE` of mysql .
2. Is it possible that instead of showing records on web page from mysql response i just use this csv file to bind my gridview ? or right custom HTML ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want show million of records the best way is "slickgrid", may be it will help you.

https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid

https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Used-by

https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Examples